# Merging different CSV files

Tags: python, csv, merge, append, concatenation

I want to merge different files based on the conditions of the file names. For example,

```
Name1_Stuff1_A.csv  
Name1_Stuff1_B.csv  
Name1_Stuff2_A.csv    
Name1_Stuff2_B.csv    
Name1_Stuff3_A.csv  
Name1_Stuff3_B.csv
```

Merging:

```
Name1_Stuff1_A + Name1_Stuff2_A + Name1_Stuff3_A -> Name1_Total_A  
Name1_Stuff1_B + Name1_Stuff2_B + Name1_Stuff3_B -> Name1_Total_B  
Then move on to another name, e.g., Name2, and so on
```

I tried:

```
    for name in names:
        with open('{}_Total_A.csv'.format(name), 'a') as merged_file:
            for file in glob.glob('*.csv'):
                for line in open(file, 'r'):
                    merged_file.write(line)
```

But it only returned A (no B):

```
    Name1_Total_A.csv
    Name2_Total_A.csv
```

And the A files are merged with all files.

How can I do this:

```
    Name1_Total_A.csv
    Name2_Total_B.csv
    Name1_Total_A.csv
    Name2_Total_B.csv
```

where Name1_Total_A.csv is merged in the order of Name1_Stuff1_A.csv, Name1_Stuff2_A.csv, and Name1_Stuff3_A.csv, and so are the other files

Thanks!

Comment: I really think you're at the point of trying your own ideas out before asking us. Your computer won't explode if those two approaches don't work :) Try them, if there's issues, try to build on them, and if you get completely stuck, ask a question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
In general, "will this work" questions are best addressed to the ultimate authority: the Python run-time system.  :-)

Comment: Thanks @roganjosh and Prune for your kind response. Sorry, this is the first time I'm posting questions here. I tried the for loop but not the split. The for loop would return all files that have the format in *_D.csv. So it consolidated Peter, John, Jack, Joe in one single file, which was not what I wanted. I know the problem should be caused by the for loop, like how I structured it. But I'm really stuck there. Could you please shed some light on it? It's appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show examples of your CSV files and how you want your merged CSV file to appear.

Comment: Thanks @MartinEvans. I think it should be clearer now.

Comment: Do the files contain headers? If so are they all the same? Do the merged files need just one header?

Comment: @MartinEvans Yes they all contain the same headers. But I'm fine as long as I can merge the files accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could condense the code as follows:

```
from itertools import product

for name, ab in product(range(1, 4), ['A', 'B']):
    with open('Name{}_Total_{}.csv'.format(name, ab), 'a') as merged_file:
        for stuff in range(1, 4):
            with open('/Name{}_Stuff{}_{}.csv'.format(name, stuff, ab), 'r') as f_input:
                merged_file.write(f_input.read())
```

The [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is another way of writing nested for loops. Try adding some `print` statements to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer, but it's so tedious. Is there any way to make it more efficient? Thanks.

```
for each_name in names:
    with open('/{}_Total_A.csv'.format(each_name), 'a') as merged_file:
        stuff1 = open('/{}_Stuff1_A.csv'.format(each_name), 'r').read()
        merged_file.write(stuff1)
        stuff2 = open('/{}_Stuff2_A.csv'.format(each_name), 'r').read()
        merged_file.write(stuff2)
        stuff3 = open('/{}_Stuff3_A.csv'.format(each_name), 'r').read()
        merged_file.write(stuff3)

    with open('/{}_Total_B.csv'.format(each_name), 'a') as merged_file:
        stuff1 = open('/{}_Stuff1_B.csv'.format(each_name), 'r').read()
        merged_file.write(stuff1)
        stuff2 = open('/{}_Stuff2_B.csv'.format(each_name), 'r').read()
        merged_file.write(stuff2)
        stuff3 = open('/{}_Stuff3_B.csv'.format(each_name), 'r').read()
        merged_file.write(stuff3)
```